# How to get the average of a DATEDIFF()?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(day, DateUsed, DateExpires) AS DaysBetweenExpirationAndUse
FROM tblOffer
```

How could i get the average number of days from the `DaysBetweenExpirationAndUse` column?

Comment: Can you post your code where you attempted to use AVG?

Comment: What do you mean by "obviously doesn't work"? I would have assumed it works. Do you get wrong results or an error message? Which results do you get, and how does it differ from what you get? What are the error messages? One thing I could imagine counter-intuitive is that SQL Server `AVG` does the averaging with integer logic for integer input. If this is the issue, using `AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(d, DateUsed, DateExpires) as FLOAT))` might give a more intuitive result.

Comment: For future reference, the phrase "didn't work" is too vague to be useful.  Keep that in mind next time you request assistance.

Comment: Agreed with the others about how useless "didn't work" is. If your original question had included the *actual code you were trying* and *the error message you were receiving*, it would have been a lot more obvious. Garbage in, garbage out. Don't be surprised to be getting feedback when you ask a crap question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(d, DateUsed, DateExpires)) AS AvgDaysBetweenExpirationAndUse 
FROM tbl
```

If you want decimal places in your AVG:

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(d, DateUsed, DateExpires)*1.0) AS AvgDaysBetweenExpirationAndUse 
FROM tbl
```

If you want to select the `AVG` and other fields too, without grouping:

```
SELECT *
      ,AVG(DATEDIFF(d, DateUsed, DateExpires)*1.0) OVER() AS AvgDaysBetweenExpirationAndUse 
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 4):

this sql could execute?

```
SELECT AVG(t.a) from
  (
    SELECT DATEDIFF(d, DateUsed, DateExpires) AS a 
    FROM tbl
  ) as t
```

this is my test:

[image]

but good answer is:

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(d, DateOne, DateTwo)*1.0) AS avgDate
    FROM Test
```

Comment: It may execute, but it may fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(d, DateUsed, DateExpires)) FROM tbl
```

should work fine. Note, that since `DATEDIFF` returns an integer value, the result also will be an integer.

If you want the "exact" (as far as floating point gets) average, use

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(d, DateUsed, DateExpires) AS FLOAT)) FORM tbl
```